# How to fix error "Cannot resolve column..."

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

I am developing Java web application what based on Spring Framework, MySQL, JPA. I have a problem when try to persistence data from HTML form to SQL database, then I try to debug and fix. I am using *IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1*. I catch error:

> Cannot resolve column 'product_name' This inspection controls whether
>   the Persistence ORM annotations are checked against configured
>   Datasources

This is screenshot:
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Persistence tool windows, right click on module, then set DataSource. IntelliJ IDEA will validate source code by real SQL database.
[image]

Comment: I cannot find a tool window 'Persistence'. Where is it?

Comment: You must enable facet `JPA`

Comment: If you made a schema change you may need to refresh datasources.

Answer (score 18):

For those who just want to disable this check, go to
Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Search "**Unresolved database references in annotations**" and uncheck it. 
[image]
(macOS Mojave and Intellij Ultimate 2019.3)
This will disable the inspection and remove all the "Cannot resolve column…" errors on the `@Column` annotations. Intellij will stop checking if the String column names exist in the database tables. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer to deal with ephemeral in-memory databases such as H2, during development -- had this problem after upgrading to Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage your data sources. I followed the steps detailed here
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-data-sources.html.

In my case, I did the following (I am using Pycharms, but I assume the process is similar for other Jetbrains IDEs):

- Bring the Data sources and drivers window by going to `view` > `tool windows` > `database`

  [image]
- Click the wrench icon to configure the db connection

  [image]
- Configure it, and try that the connection works with `Test Connection`

  [image]

---

Pycharms should now autocomplete fields in the db.

If it still doesn't work:

- try restarting Pycharms.
- go to options (command + `,`), then search for SQL, select menu `SQL Resolution Scopes`, and try adding a scope by clicking `+`, then selecting your current project folder as path, and your db as the resolution scope

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a **TEMPORARY** work around for this bug.
Please before you follow my workaround do **exactly** what @[Benjamin Crouzier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311744/benjamin-crouzier)'s answer suggests. **THEN**, go to any of the unresolved columns, right click it and they click execute. and **Boom** annoying warning SOLVED :)

[image: phpstorm fix warning]

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions above, I solved this by clicking `Refresh` in the database tool window.

[image: refresh]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by changing double quote (") for single quote ('). You can read the doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).