# How to fix the issue: "Unable to resolve column ''" if part of fields are specified correct in the script?

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following [script](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/resources/data.sql#L4) below as:

```
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Employees                                             */
/*==============================================================*/
insert into Employees (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, salary, role, password, username)
values ('Christiano', 'Ronaldo', '+421905123456', 'test@gmail.com', 50000.00, 'TEAM_LEADER', 'testPassword', 'C7'),
       ('John', 'Smith', '+421905123480', 'test2@gmail.com', 40000.00, 'PM', 'testPassword2', 'Jo'),
       ('Michael', 'Jackson', '+421905123400', 'test3@gmail.com', 30000.00, 'DEVELOPER', 'testPassword3', 'Mike'),
       ('Leonardo', 'DiCaprio', '+421905123450', 'test4@gmail.com', 20000.00, 'SCIENTIST', 'testPassword4', 'Leo'),
       ('Brad', 'Pitt', '+421905123455', 'test5@gmail.com', 10000.00, 'ENGINEER', 'testPassword5', 'Brad');
```

My [entity](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/data/models/Employee.java#L24) as:

```
import com.test.application.data.enums.Role;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author invzbl3 on 12/16/2022
 * @project RestApiApplication
 */
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity(name = "employee_entity")
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private double salary;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(() -> "USER");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've checked similar question, but it doesn't look the same for me, because I have part of fields correctly marked there:

[How to fix error "Cannot resolve column..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43739438/8370915)

I've checked several times correspondence of the field names in own entity, no problems were found.

Based on it, my question is:

does anyone know how can I fix the issue here?

If you need some additional help, I'm ready to provide.

The error message is:

```
Unable to resolve column...
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any helpful ideas.

Comment: Please add your error message to your question.

Comment: Sure, I've added the error message in the question.

Comment: That's just a warning from your IDE.

Comment: The problem is: because of this warning, the data is not polulating partly. Specifically, the insert where's the error message.

Comment: I understood the problem. For some reason, in the table I have another name of these fields as: `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`.

Comment: I have some progress with this question, I'll write updates a bit later in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to [Spring Data naming convention](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-custom-naming), for this reason, I've improved the `Employee` entity with additional annotation `@JsonProperty` for specific columnns with *underscore*.

as:

```
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity(name = "employee_entity")
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private double salary;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(() -> "USER");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```